# Question on compact subsets of finite dimensional normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm trying to prove this fact:

If $X$ is a finite dimensional normed space and $K$ a compact subset of $X$ that satisfies that if $x, y \in K$ then $\frac{x-y}{2} \in K$ then, given $a \in X \setminus K$ there exists an $\varepsilon >1$ such that $a \not \in\varepsilon K$

I know that the distance from $a$ to $K$ is greater than zero and is attained by some point $x \in K$, so I'm trying to prove that is enough to take $1 < \varepsilon < d(a,K)+1$ but I'm not able to reach a contradiction if I suppose that $a \in \varepsilon K$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true for all compact $K$ and, in fact, for $a\notin K$ the set $\{\varepsilon\in \Bbb R\,:\, a\notin \varepsilon K\}$ contains a neighbourhood of $1$ regardless of any other condition on $K$. For, if there were a sequence $\varepsilon_n\to 1$ such that $a\in\varepsilon_n K$ for all $n$, then there would be a sequence $x_n\in K$ such that $a=\varepsilon_nx_n$ for all $n$. By considering a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}\to x\in K$, we obtain $a=\lim_{k\to\infty}\varepsilon_{n_k}x_{n_k}=x$.

Answer (score 3):

It is sufficient to assume that $K$ is closed in a topological vector space. Namely $K^c$ is open and $1 \cdot a \in K^c$ so by continuity of scalar multiplication, there exist $s,t > 0$ such that
$$\langle 1-s, 1+s\rangle \cdot B(a,t) \subseteq K^c.$$
In particular, for $\varepsilon := 1+\frac{s}2$ we have $\varepsilon a \in K^c$.

Comment: Oh, damn. How could I not see that?